# Self-referenced array with lazy evaluation

Tags: javascript, arrays, lazy-evaluation

I was playing with JavaScript arrays and, by accident, pushed an array to itself. Instead of breaking with an overflow exception, the array lazily inserted a reference to itself going on to infinite. In an operation where:

```
x = [], x.push(x)
```

A reference to itself will be inserted, I belive, recursively, but without a runtime break. It will generate an infinite representation:

[image]

And the browser never freezes or break, probabily because the value is """evaluated""" on click.

- *Why does it behave like this?*
- *How can the V8 handle cyclic references?*
- *Does it have any utility in the real world programming?*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An infinite structure that doesn't take up an infinite amount of memory isn't inherently unstable or unusable. And V8 doesn't have to do anything special to handle cyclic references AFAIK. It's not much different than having a linked list connected front-to-back in a ring, for instance. I'm having trouble understanding why you believe it shouldn't work.

Comment: Or `x = {}; x.x = x;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *Why does it behave like this?*

While the graphical representation may show infinite "arrays", you are in fact having a recursive one, so, you have only 1, in memory, that the `first` element contains an array (but just a pointer to one). If you add a second member to the first array, all of them should now show the same members, because they are the same.

- *How can the V8 handle cyclic references?*

I am unaware if it can or not... but I do know that javascript allows you to writte senseless code.

- *Does it have any utility in the real world programming?*

While it may seem impratical, the concept of "sets" representation, you could for instance have:

1. The set that only contains itself.
2. The set that contains all sets that contain nothing (only filled with    itself when all other sets contain something else).
3. The set that contains sets that are currently being contained.

These can be usef for something like grouping controls...

Overall, self refferences are usually "non-sequitur", mainly because in computers you already have a refference to a variable (thus negating the need for additional self-refferences) and usually people organize their programs to facilitate something... either less operations, or maintenance or something they preffer.